# Making your own Pod for MonkeyTalk

Tags: cocoapods

I am new to CocoaPods. I was looking through the list of Pods and did not see one for [MonkeyTalk](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk). I decided to try and create one. I think I have everything I need filled out correctly, but got a `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:918: [BUG] Segmentation fault` and `Abort trap: 6` error. I do not know why. MonkeyTalk requires the following library and frameworks to run: `libMonkeyTalk-2.0.4.a`, `libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib`, `CFNetwork.framework`, `QuartzCore.framework`. I have attached what my directory looks like below and heres a [link to my .podspec file.](http://pastebin.com/ajqQQYXD)

[image: Directory]

Comment: I've updated your [.podspec](http://pastebin.com/SaTiLzq8) file

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an issue with the installation of CocoaPods. You should reinstall it:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Just tried that and got the same issue with building the Pod